# C#: Is there an "Optional" keyword or alike in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to mark a parameter as optional like VB.net's Optional keyword?

Comment: Is there something wrong with overloading your methods and setting/handling defaults?

Comment: What Simon is describing is shown in full in Noldorin's answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There will be in C# 4.0

For now you can either overload your method, set a default value and call the other method. Or set it to nullable.

```
public void DoSomething(int a)
{
   int defaultValue = 1;
   DoSomething(a, defaultValue);
}

public void DoSomething(int a, int b)
{
    // Do something
}
```

or

```
public void DoSomething(int a, int? b)
{
   // Check for b.HasValue and do what you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Up until C# 3.0, I'm afraid it is not possible, at least *per se*. (See later section of post.)

With the advent of C# 4.0, you could do something like the following:

```
void FooMethod(int foo, string bar = "foobar")
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, "{1}", foo, bar);
}
```

Any parameter given a default value is necessarily an [**optional arguement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(VS.100).aspx).

Which could be called in the following ways:

```
FooBar(123"); // Outputs: "123, foobar"
FooBar(123, "hello"); // Outputs: "123, hello"
FooBar(123, bar: "hello"); // Outputs: "123, hello"
```

In earlier versions of C#, you might achieve the same by [**operator overloading**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739(VS.100).aspx).

```
void FooMethod(int foo)
{
    FooMethod(foo, "foobar");
}

void FooMethod(int foo, string bar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", foo, bar);
}
```

**Note**:
It is important here not to confuse *what* has been lacking support for optional arguments. The .NET framework (CLR/CIL language) have supported them for a while now (possible always), and the VB.NET language makes use of this. It is only with *C# 4.0* however, that C# specifically makes makes use of the feature.

Comment: You are missing a " on the first FooBar(123").

Comment: Also, you can have overloaded constructors without a body tbh. void FooMethod(Int32 foo) : this(foo, "foobar") { } void FooMethod(Int32 foo, String bar) { /* set fields, properties, et cetera here */ }

Comment: Zack: We're talking about methods here. Chaining in such a way only works on constructors.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in .NET 4.0 version.
Earlier versions don't provide this functionality.

Comment: I'm tempted to down-vote, because this is technically incorrect. All versions of .NET (as far as I'm aware) have allowed optional arguments, in that the CLR/CIL language support them. Clearly, VB.NET's support of Optional is evidence. It is only with the creation of C# 4.0 that they are available in *the C# language*. There was nothing stopping you writing methods with optional arguments in CIL/VB.NET previously.

Answer (score 1):

Not until C# 4.0, sadly. David Hayden has a blog post [here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/06/02/CSharp4OptionalNamedParameters.aspx) detailing how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's coming in C# 4.0. See [this](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/06/02/CSharp4OptionalNamedParameters.aspx) source.

Right now the best you can do is fake it hard and good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the params modifier?

```
public void Foo( int i, double d, param string[] values )
{
    foreach( String s in values )
        Bar(s);
}

private Bar( String s )
{
    //do something
}
```

For this definition, all of the following calls are legit:

```
Foo( 1, 3.14 )
Foo( 2, 1.6128 )
Foo( 3, 3.14, "This", "is", "a", "test" );
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to create multiple objects(functions,procedures) with different parameters. or more cleanly create an object type to pass as a param and have logic in the function to do that type of optional logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you're stuck with overloading until then.